# Python regex to match multiple times

Tags: python, regex, multiple-matches

I'm trying to match a pattern against strings that could have multiple instances of the pattern. I need every instance separately. `re.findall()` *should* do it but I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
pattern = re.compile('/review: (http://url.com/(\d+)\s?)+/', re.IGNORECASE)
match = pattern.findall('this is the message. review: http://url.com/123 http://url.com/456')
```

I need 'http://url.com/123', http://url.com/456 and the two numbers 123 & 456 to be different elements of the `match` list.

I have also tried `'/review: ((http://url.com/(\d+)\s?)+)/'` as the pattern, but no luck.

Comment: just remove the review: portion as the second http won't have that before it.

Comment: yes but I need that there, it's part of the regex. I don't need ANY url there, just the ones following the string 'review:'

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use this. You need to place 'review' outside the capturing group to achieve the desired result.

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(?:review: )?(http://url.com/(\d+))\s?', re.IGNORECASE)
```

This gives output

```
>>> match = pattern.findall('this is the message. review: http://url.com/123 http://url.com/456')
>>> match
[('http://url.com/123', '123'), ('http://url.com/456', '456')]
```

Comment: that does the job, thanks! the `?` after `(?:review )` is also critical as it didn't give me all matches without it. ;)

Comment: Don't forget to `import re`

Comment: What about doing it without `findall`? I.e. for cases when you need to match many cases, but this would be just a part of a match?

Comment: https://regex101.com/ is a neat tool for testing this out.

Answer (score 6):

You've got extra /'s in the regex.  In python the pattern should just be a string. e.g. instead of this:

```
pattern = re.compile('/review: (http://url.com/(\d+)\s?)+/', re.IGNORECASE)
```

It should be:

```
pattern = re.compile('review: (http://url.com/(\d+)\s?)+', re.IGNORECASE)
```

Also typically in python you'd actually use a "raw" string like this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r'review: (http://url.com/(\d+)\s?)+', re.IGNORECASE)
```

The extra r on the front of the string saves you from having to do lots of backslash escaping etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use a two-step approach: First get everything from "review:" to EOL, then tokenize that.

```
msg = 'this is the message. review: http://url.com/123 http://url.com/456'

review_pattern = re.compile('.*review: (.*)$')
urls = review_pattern.findall(msg)[0]

url_pattern = re.compile("(http://url.com/(\d+))")
url_pattern.findall(urls)
```